# Irregular sounds on new 50mm wheels at speeds over 16mph

Tags: wheels, carbon

I just bought new Chinese Carbon 50mm tubular wheels and I have a number of noises that are driving me crazy.  There is a whistling or irregular whooshing sound on every rotation.  Besides the normal white noise constant.  Is it just me or do other people have irregular sounds at speed over 16mph.  Wheels are true and round with new mavic tubulars.

Please let me know if anyone else has a rotation noise issue.   My aluminum campy wheels are dead quiet.  Thanks. Ken

Comment: I'm guessing these are the cheap POS on ebay. You get what you pay for with wheels.

Comment: Earplugs are fairly cheap.

Comment: Likely the sound is air whistling through some opening in the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, the deeper the rim the more noise the wheel makes. A pronounced whooshing noise isn't unusual among deep dish wheels and disc wheels (as in the solid wheels, not the brakes) are even noisier. I had Cinelli and Hed discs when I raced and used to love the sound of them (the ride, not so much!)

I would personally be very nervous of the no brand Chinese carbon wheels, frames and parts being sold on eBay. I've been hearing some absolute horror stories from shops and race mechanics.